# Opening powerpoint and word documents on Android using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently using a Corodova plugin [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md) to open files. It's working fine on iOS but not on Android. I found out that Android's browser doesn't support viewing files, so you have to use the system.

The problem I'm having, I think, is that I don't know the how to get the path to the file.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.onResourceClick = function(url){
    window.open(url, '_system', 'location=no');
};
```

url is the relative path to the file, from the index.html in www folder.

So I think my question is, how do I get the absolute path to the file.

I'm making progress. Using [Cordova's file plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) I can get a few different paths. Still unsure which to use and where exactly the file is being stored at.

I'm using cordovaFile.checkFile to check if there is a file at the path I try, and I'm just kinda guessing for now to see if I can get lucky and find it.

```
$cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, url)
    .then(function (success) {
        alert('yay' + success);
    }, function (error) {
        alert('nah' + error);
    });
```

I've tried

- `cordova.file.dataDirectory`
- `cordova.file.applicationDirectory`

and appending to the end of each of those, the path from the www folder to my file, and just the file name. I'm hoping I can get lucky and find the right combination to the file, because I can't seem to find an answer researching.

Edit:

The workflow for what I'm trying to do has changed.
I'm now storing the files on a server and using an api to return the url to the file. Then downloading the file onto the device, and then opening it.

Currently I have everything except the download method working.

```
$cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, resourceFullName, resource.DocumentURL, true)
```

The download method is only downloading 100bytes of the file.

I think this may be because the writeFile method is asking for Data, and I'm giving it the URL to the file, rather than txt. It looks like my current question is, how do I download a file to the device.

Comment: file is in your WWW directory ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Yes it is.

Comment: I think you want the file transfer plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Comment: That's what I'm trying out now Connor. Thanks for the link to the documentation, the github wasn't documented as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of other issues you may be having:

The system browser may not have permission to open files in your application's www directory.

I don't believe Android's browser supports PDFs or Powerpoints. As Murtaza suggested, there are plugins that will allow you to open documents in another app. You could also look into [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render PDFs in a webview.

For downloading files you should use the file transfer plugin. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Comment: This answers the original question. My problem was the permissions needed to open the file, and since the file is stored in a directory that is private to the application I was not able to open the file in another app. Moving the file to a public location fixes this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following [File Opener Plugin](https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener)

**Sample Use**

```
window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///sdcard/Android/data/com.example.application/manual.pdf");
```

Comment: I installed File Opener and I'm first saving the file to cordova.file.externalDataDirectory (Android/data/<app-id>/files/) The plugin prompts to select the app it opens in. My only option is POLARIS Office 5. It opens, but then gives me an error "An error occurred while opening the document"

Comment: Your device specs and which cordova/phonegap version you are using?

Comment: I just tried opening the file that's being downloaded, on the computer, and it seems that it's corrupt. I'm using $cordovaFile.writeFile to download the file and it doesn't look like it's downloading the entire file.